# What is this serif font used in an MIT working papers' book?

Tags: font-identification

I tried different websites and asked different people, but nothing helped. I am struggling to identify the font in this picture. The publisher of this book is MIT (1998). Precisely, it is MIT working papers in Linguistics.

Could you please help me?

[image]

Comment: The photograph is really bad quality, so it's hard to tell for sure, but it looks like some variant of Times.  To identify a font accurately, you really need a much better quality image.

Comment: Sorry, that's no better. It looks like the print is horrible quality.  Still only possible to make the same guess unfortunately.

Comment: yes you're right. The book was printed this way. It looks blurry. I liked this font a lot, and I've been struggling to identify it for a week now. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: You should learn here that there is a reason we use black text. Not some lighter shade, it may look ok on screen but horrible in print.

Comment: @joojaa I didn't use any shade & the original text is indeed in black. I took this picture with a smartphone. Please tell me what to do to make it look better so that someone will be able to identify the font.

Comment: @Tsutsu - joojaa means that text should be printed in 100% black. The problem with the print is that it probably wasn't 100% black, which would cause it to print badly on a laser printer or in lithographic printing - causing it to print with a half-tone pattern.  He's not saying it's something you printed, just mentioning a way to avoid such problems occurring if you do any printing.  There is nothing you can do to make this look better if you didn't print it. It's too late for that. What's done is done!

Comment: I see now, thanks. The problem is that Publishing Houses do not reveal the fonts they use. I don't know why, may be they invented them, and they want their books to look distinct. This font is also similar to a font used by Springer (used to be).

Comment: @Tsutsu I didn't confirm this but it looks like Times New Roman printed poorly...

Comment: Your friends left some things out; they should have suggested to read the [tour] as well as the [requirements for font identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions).

Comment: @curious It could be variant of it as Billy Kerr suggested, but it's not TNR, because as I mentioned in my last comment, it was used also by Springer. It's not a question of printing although the quality here is catastrophic.

Comment: @usr2564301 I did try some of the tools like WhatTheFont, & the font they suggest are closer in shape, but when I try them on MS Word, they don't look the same. This is why one of my friends suggested to consult professional designers.

Comment: @Tsutsu Why wouldn't it also be used by Springer? When I write in APA style this is what I'm required to use

Comment: @curious do they publish with TNR? I have this article https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11049-004-5927-z and it's printed in a font similar to the one in the picture above. And this article was published in 2005. I'm not saying it's not TNR, yes, it's too close to it, but I think it's customized, probably.

Comment: @Tsutsu They can take the articles and change the formatting to whatever is used by the publisher, but customized fonts are more the exception than the norm in publishing. The design on the screenshot is very crude: double-leading, everything is the same size... I would be very very surprised if this were a customized font. Nothing around it suggests that.

Comment: @curious I forgot to mention something. This book is neither A4 nor A5, it's something in between. Do you think changing the page setup may shrink the font? Especially if it's a scanned document?

Comment: @tsutsu I can't answer that, it depends on settings used but it's very possible

Comment: @Tsutsu, I've tried retyping portions in the standard system version of TNR and it seems almost identical. They probably justified the lines to make it look neat as some of the spaces vary in widths. Don't worry about the grousing above-it's a perfectly good enough sample to identify from. My guess is it looks so bad because it's photocopied.

Comment: @Copilot thank you. So they justified it high? Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Copilot Nice seeing your comments here! Since you've come closest to confirming the font, would you mind posting an answer?

Comment: "I did try some of the tools like WhatTheFont" -- and that's why there is a strong suggestion to [**read that link on Font Identification Questions**](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions): (1) you tried it but did not mention that; (2) with those, you got a few suggestions, but you did not mention that; (3) the suggested fonts may or may not be 'close enough' but you left out which ones and why they did not answer your question. And that is why some of us are just repeating what that site already told you.

Comment: There's a good chance that's the Times/Times Roman font that is the default on Postscript laser printers.